# Iphone App was Rejected Due to We found your app crashed on launch so we were unable to review it

Tags: ios, iphone, itunes-store

published my app to the appstore but it was rejected because of the following reason:

Please revise your app and test it on a device to ensure it will launch without crashing,    and that it runs as expected, before resubmitting.

Can anybody help me out; how to solve this problem ?

First Crash File

```
{"app_name":"SELFAPP","app_version":"1.1.0","bundleID":"com.tbits.ae.Fit4Skool","adam_id":912203744,"os_version":"iPhone OS 8.1 (12B410)","slice_uuid":"72b233f9-af11-38c8-ac05-cc591d30ca16","share_with_app_devs":false,"build_version":"1.1.0","is_first_party":false,"bug_type":"109","name":"SELFAPP"}
Incident Identifier: 6D10D2BB-3233-484C-A204-EB960DB9C49B
CrashReporter Key:   46c7852fac0c51f80f55811497664c2095477bb4
Hardware Model:      xxx
Process:             SELFAPP [331]
Path:                /private/var/mobile/Containers/Bundle/Application/ED53D678-2E47-4ED8-B04C-351DE058CC21/SELFAPP.app/SELFAPP
Identifier:          com.tbits.ae.Fit4Skool
Version:             1.1.0 (1.1.0)
Code Type:           ARM-64 (Native)
Parent Process:      launchd [1]

Date/Time:           2015-01-02 09:07:29.502 -0800
Launch Time:         2015-01-02 09:07:28.224 -0800
OS Version:          iOS 8.1 (12B410)
Report Version:      105

Exception Type:  EXC_BAD_ACCESS (SIGSEGV)
Exception Subtype: KERN_INVALID_ADDRESS at 0x0000000000001da0
Triggered by Thread:  0

Thread 0 name:  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread
Thread 0 Crashed:
0   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x000000019634c0b4 objc_retain + 20
1   SELFAPP                         0x000000010015e034 0x1000f4000 + 434228
2   SELFAPP                         0x000000010015c7f4 0x1000f4000 + 428020
3   CoreFoundation                  0x000000018568c1dc __CFNOTIFICATIONCENTER_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_AN_OBSERVER__ + 16
4   CoreFoundation                  0x00000001855cb36c _CFXNotificationPost + 2056
5   Foundation                      0x00000001864c6cbc -[NSNotificationCenter postNotificationName:object:userInfo:] + 68
6   SELFAPP                         0x000000010015b6b0 0x1000f4000 + 423600
7   Foundation                      0x00000001865b5dec __NSThreadPerformPerform + 368
8   CoreFoundation                  0x000000018569e0e4 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE0_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ + 20
9   CoreFoundation                  0x000000018569d388 __CFRunLoopDoSources0 + 260
10  CoreFoundation                  0x000000018569b438 __CFRunLoopRun + 708
11  CoreFoundation                  0x00000001855c91f0 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 392
12  GraphicsServices                0x000000018e7435a0 GSEventRunModal + 164
13  UIKit                           0x0000000189efa780 UIApplicationMain + 1484
14  SELFAPP                         0x00000001001083a4 0x1000f4000 + 82852
15  libdyld.dylib                   0x00000001969a2a04 start + 0

Thread 1 name:  Dispatch queue: com.apple.libdispatch-manager
Thread 1:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x0000000196aa0c94 kevent64 + 8
1   libdispatch.dylib               0x000000019698897c _dispatch_mgr_invoke + 272
2   libdispatch.dylib               0x000000019697b3b0 _dispatch_mgr_thread + 48

Thread 2:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x0000000196abbc78 __workq_kernreturn + 8
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000196b55390 _pthread_wqthread + 988
2   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000196b54fa4 start_wqthread + 0

Thread 3:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x0000000196abbc78 __workq_kernreturn + 8
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000196b55390 _pthread_wqthread + 988
2   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000196b54fa4 start_wqthread + 0

Thread 4 name:  Dispatch queue: com.apple.NSURLSession-work
Thread 4:
0   CFNetwork                       0x000000018517c5a8 RunLoopSchedulingSet::performAsync(void () block_pointer) const + 28
1   CFNetwork                       0x000000018512f8bc URLConnectionLoader::_onqueue_loaderEvent_CancelLoad(dispatch_queue_s*, void () block_pointer, URLProtocol*) + 176
2   CFNetwork                       0x000000018512f8bc URLConnectionLoader::_onqueue_loaderEvent_CancelLoad(dispatch_queue_s*, void () block_pointer, URLProtocol*) + 176
3   CFNetwork                       0x000000018505f560 ___ZN19URLConnectionLoader23_loaderEvent_CancelLoadEP16dispatch_queue_sU13block_pointerFvvE_block_invoke + 44
4   CFNetwork                       0x000000018512468c ___ZNK25URLConnectionInstanceData18withWorkQueueAsyncEU13block_pointerFvvE_block_invoke + 24
5   libdispatch.dylib               0x00000001969793a8 _dispatch_call_block_and_release + 20
6   libdispatch.dylib               0x0000000196979368 _dispatch_client_callout + 12
7   libdispatch.dylib               0x00000001969834bc _dispatch_queue_drain + 1212
8   libdispatch.dylib               0x000000019697c470 _dispatch_queue_invoke + 128
9   libdispatch.dylib               0x0000000196985220 _dispatch_root_queue_drain + 660
10  libdispatch.dylib               0x0000000196986758 _dispatch_worker_thread3 + 104
11  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000196b552e0 _pthread_wqthread + 812
12  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000196b54fa4 start_wqthread + 0

Thread 5:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x0000000196abbc78 __workq_kernreturn + 8
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000196b55390 _pthread_wqthread + 988
2   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000196b54fa4 start_wqthread + 0

Thread 6 name:  com.apple.NSURLConnectionLoader
Thread 6:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x0000000196aa0e7c mach_msg_trap + 8
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x0000000196aa0cf4 mach_msg + 68
2   CoreFoundation                  0x000000018569d5c8 __CFRunLoopServiceMachPort + 196
3   CoreFoundation                  0x000000018569b51c __CFRunLoopRun + 936
4   CoreFoundation                  0x00000001855c91f0 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 392
5   CFNetwork                       0x00000001850cd6a0 +[NSURLConnection(Loader) _resourceLoadLoop:] + 436
6   Foundation                      0x00000001865b5c08 __NSThread__main__ + 1068
7   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000196b57e7c _pthread_body + 160
8   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000196b57dd8 _pthread_start + 156
9   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000196b54fac thread_start + 0

Thread 7 name:  com.apple.CFSocket.private
Thread 7:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x0000000196abb498 __select + 8
1   CoreFoundation                  0x00000001856a2fc0 __CFSocketManager + 656
2   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000196b57e7c _pthread_body + 160
3   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000196b57dd8 _pthread_start + 156
4   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000196b54fac thread_start + 0

Thread 8:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x0000000196abb078 __psynch_cvwait + 8
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000196b56fe0 _pthread_cond_wait + 620
2   Foundation                      0x0000000186523cbc -[NSCondition wait] + 244
3   Foundation                      0x00000001864e2ed4 -[NSObject(NSThreadPerformAdditions) performSelector:onThread:withObject:waitUntilDone:modes:] + 712
4   Foundation                      0x00000001864e709c -[NSObject(NSThreadPerformAdditions) performSelectorOnMainThread:withObject:waitUntilDone:] + 156
5   SELFAPP                         0x000000010015b7d4 0x1000f4000 + 423892
6   Foundation                      0x00000001865b5c08 __NSThread__main__ + 1068
7   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000196b57e7c _pthread_body + 160
8   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000196b57dd8 _pthread_start + 156
9   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000196b54fac thread_start + 0

Thread 0 crashed with ARM Thread State (64-bit):
    x0: 0x00000001700d2608   x1: 0x000000018a664f66   x2: 0x00000001700d2608   x3: 0x0000000196af5a74
    x4: 0x000000017007b140   x5: 0x0000000000000000   x6: 0x00000001700d49f8   x7: 0x0000000000000a80
    x8: 0x0000000000001d80   x9: 0x000000000077e1c0  x10: 0x000000000077e101  x11: 0x0000000000607000
   x12: 0x0000000000000063  x13: 0x0000000000000000  x14: 0x0000007f47542f08  x15: 0x00000000000000c8
   x16: 0x000000019634c0a0  x17: 0x000000010015e018  x18: 0x0000000000000000  x19: 0x000000017008e8d0
   x20: 0x0000000125514e50  x21: 0x0000000125514e50  x22: 0x000000017808b630  x23: 0x000000018a664f66
   x24: 0x000000018a6654ef  x25: 0x00000001700d2600  x26: 0x000000018a6740ed  x27: 0x0000000170053cb0
   x28: 0x000000017008e8d0  fp: 0x000000016fd0a5d0   lr: 0x000000010015e038
    sp: 0x000000016fd0a590   pc: 0x000000019634c0b4 cpsr: 0x20000000

Binary Images:
0x1000f4000 - 0x1001ebfff SELFAPP arm64  <72b233f9af1138c8ac05cc591d30ca16> /var/mobile/Containers/Bundle/Application/ED53D678-2E47-4ED8-B04C-351DE058CC21/SELFAPP.app/SELFAPP
0x120054000 - 0x12007bfff dyld arm64  <f958ba064181388a9658f927da42e9e7> /usr/lib/dyld
0x183ec0000 - 0x184053fff AVFoundation arm64  <0c542593e3613f82b7e860cb5beeeed6> /System/Library/Frameworks/AVFoundation.framework/AVFoundation
0x184054000 - 0x1840b8fff libAVFAudio.dylib arm64  <c9d296cb28c73570aaf8355b05f1adee> /System/Library/Frameworks/AVFoundation.framework/libAVFAudio.dylib
0x1840fc000 - 0x1840fcfff Accelerate arm64  <e9ba7838f51634a7b59ed392be50e86f> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Accelerate
0x184114000 - 0x184333fff vImage arm64  <da44067fc79931c7aef1b7e88bf82a83> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Frameworks/vImage.framework/vImage
0x184334000 - 0x1843dbfff libBLAS.dylib arm64  <e5276e7784ef34a4baca480264978ea0> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/libBLAS.dylib
0x1843dc000 - 0x184756fff libLAPACK.dylib arm64  <165b05f9f75736d5ae8f5f39293bd6e7> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/libLAPACK.dylib
0x184758000 - 0x18476dfff libLinearAlgebra.dylib arm64  <5574ec3bd4e537e1b662d38a63aec58b> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/libLinearAlgebra.dylib
0x184770000 - 0x1847d8fff libvDSP.dylib arm64  <004f5668574139bc906c5fa4fdced3b1> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/libvDSP.dylib
0x1847dc000 - 0x1847fffff libvMisc.dylib arm64  <5f3faba4a40930d5b5383244de9d9749> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/libvMisc.dylib
0x184800000 - 0x184800fff vecLib arm64  <211d7711a6e93fe8ae6d6b42585cad2d> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/vecLib
0x184804000 - 0x184832fff Accounts arm64  <ed248dc14d9c38feb7a61bdd532db9cc> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accounts.framework/Accounts
0x184838000 - 0x1848bafff AddressBook arm64  <191fcc882bb8300b90b0b6b55cc7eec0> /System/Library/Frameworks/AddressBook.framework/AddressBook
0x1848bc000 - 0x184a0cfff AddressBookUI arm64  <0d4f38d8108e3fc281fa3571f5f85bd4> /System/Library/Frameworks/AddressBookUI.framework/AddressBookUI
0x184bd4000 - 0x184e91fff AudioToolbox arm64  <d907319fb1e13f0ebfa2cb2281d63201> /System/Library/Frameworks/AudioToolbox.framework/AudioToolbox
0x185030000 - 0x18523afff CFNetwork arm64  <8898a9c58fc933a8a35b924031bbecb0> /System/Library/Frameworks/CFNetwork.framework/CFNetwork
0x18523c000 - 0x1852d3fff CloudKit arm64  <b3facf88b5663757a584455e9abd485d> /System/Library/Frameworks/CloudKit.framework/CloudKit
0x1852d4000 - 0x185339fff CoreAudio arm64  <c300729562ce3d18ae27620e01047e5f> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreAudio.framework/CoreAudio
0x18535c000 - 0x18537dfff CoreBluetooth arm64  <8c8f7fcda15736969517607dceca42e2> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreBluetooth.framework/CoreBluetooth
0x185380000 - 0x1855befff CoreData arm64  <de8697dd39c23afcb7c65813ed503d71> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreData.framework/CoreData
0x1855c0000 - 0x18591bfff CoreFoundation arm64  <dd02b6d84f42391cab1b1812b68032cd> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreFoundation.framework/CoreFoundation
0x18591c000 - 0x185a7efff CoreGraphics arm64  <051c2abd476631659a137603b5fd49c3> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreGraphics.framework/CoreGraphics
0x185ad4000 - 0x185ad6fff libCGXType.A.dylib arm64  <13bc0d2fa7633ab9bdbc4ab58e4cfcab> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreGraphics.framework/Resources/libCGXType.A.dylib
0x185ad8000 - 0x185ae3fff libCMSBuiltin.A.dylib arm64  <24a1313a58d831ae907bcfad0887b88d> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreGraphics.framework/Resources/libCMSBuiltin.A.dylib
0x185cd8000 - 0x185cf6fff libRIP.A.dylib arm64  <b739a115024c3c5da8979a6a2543fc0a> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreGraphics.framework/Resources/libRIP.A.dylib
0x185cf8000 - 0x185e25fff CoreImage arm64  <427f09be3b813a25afed0aeb1ed71878> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreImage.framework/CoreImage
0x185e28000 - 0x185e85fff CoreLocation arm64  <8fffe9b832433d21866f69798d956a16> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreLocation.framework/CoreLocation
0x185ec0000 - 0x185f7efff CoreMedia arm64  <5f763134e2033c21aed1c83209592214> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreMedia.framework/CoreMedia
0x185f80000 - 0x18604efff CoreMotion arm64  <f8e5ee2eeb7837999f3ed9681cc45276> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreMotion.framework/CoreMotion
0x186050000 - 0x1860c1fff CoreTelephony arm64  <9c4733c499b33513b887e540b68f1cb5> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreTelephony.framework/CoreTelephony
0x1860c4000 - 0x1861c6fff CoreText arm64  <abc5604ba2ff3a8aa1186c2b9cf2dd34> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreText.framework/CoreText
0x1861c8000 - 0x1861e4fff CoreVideo arm64  <ef89faf9a3a1306f8a51d8ee3c84e5fc> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreVideo.framework/CoreVideo
0x1861e8000 - 0x18630cfff EventKit arm64  <7f0cb24e7ae63a7a85405bcfe339de2e> /System/Library/Frameworks/EventKit.framework/EventKit
0x1864c0000 - 0x186714fff Foundation arm64  <468d76111ff238edaa1c603530a715ce> /System/Library/Frameworks/Foundation.framework/Foundation
0x186744000 - 0x18676dfff GSS arm64  <f6e216997e2b3b1aa29bf7d40bb55732> /System/Library/Frameworks/GSS.framework/GSS
0x18682c000 - 0x186898fff IOKit arm64  <553730de003d3e269669a2f60e38ed3a> /System/Library/Frameworks/IOKit.framework/Versions/A/IOKit
0x18689c000 - 0x186b36fff ImageIO arm64  <39a9babc3d133e19a39c060774157299> /System/Library/Frameworks/ImageIO.framework/ImageIO
0x186b38000 - 0x186fd8fff JavaScriptCore arm64  <c31c2e52ff6731e089a74c73ca401313> /System/Library/Frameworks/JavaScriptCore.framework/JavaScriptCore
0x18784c000 - 0x187852fff MediaAccessibility arm64  <97418e4a2b1b3611b00481b54254858c> /System/Library/Frameworks/MediaAccessibility.framework/MediaAccessibility
0x187854000 - 0x187a6ffff MediaPlayer arm64  <9731de774ae734c8bbf0be29b8feb25f> /System/Library/Frameworks/MediaPlayer.framework/MediaPlayer
0x187a70000 - 0x187e89fff MediaToolbox arm64  <927a5c40cba63074b031d946c8abf533> /System/Library/Frameworks/MediaToolbox.framework/MediaToolbox
0x187e8c000 - 0x187f5ffff MessageUI arm64  <f48650ea35443d7e9fd6c3be33951e58> /System/Library/Frameworks/MessageUI.framework/MessageUI
0x187f60000 - 0x187fd3fff Metal arm64  <92798a9fff8a369c803301774f8c2f9b> /System/Library/Frameworks/Metal.framework/Metal
0x187fd4000 - 0x188080fff MobileCoreServices arm64  <1b5f7f094bc33fad8653cf1d6a4729ef> /System/Library/Frameworks/MobileCoreServices.framework/MobileCoreServices
0x189204000 - 0x18920efff OpenGLES arm64  <bc171bb31bd13340ae3993deb2da3cb7> /System/Library/Frameworks/OpenGLES.framework/OpenGLES
0x189214000 - 0x189215fff libCVMSPluginSupport.dylib arm64  <1ba092f66289348589981046081ca7b8> /System/Library/Frameworks/OpenGLES.framework/libCVMSPluginSupport.dylib
0x189218000 - 0x18921bfff libCoreFSCache.dylib arm64  <5888d3587c633af2ac7cf57ac15ab5e4> /System/Library/Frameworks/OpenGLES.framework/libCoreFSCache.dylib
0x18921c000 - 0x189220fff libCoreVMClient.dylib arm64  <291806c545fe3219b844a93e2fb682b4> /System/Library/Frameworks/OpenGLES.framework/libCoreVMClient.dylib
0x189224000 - 0x18922efff libGFXShared.dylib arm64  <3073047b623a3a0ebd4421a6d82efd4f> /System/Library/Frameworks/OpenGLES.framework/libGFXShared.dylib
0x189230000 - 0x18927bfff libGLImage.dylib arm64  <8541bfcc503d39ce8021beaa1ffe1eb6> /System/Library/Frameworks/OpenGLES.framework/libGLImage.dylib
0x1897dc000 - 0x189960fff QuartzCore arm64  <376edab4d56635ec984b87b7a1702de0> /System/Library/Frameworks/QuartzCore.framework/QuartzCore
0x189964000 - 0x1899bffff QuickLook arm64  <2f3004794fe33758bd10c9a65952bca7> /System/Library/Frameworks/QuickLook.framework/QuickLook
0x189bf4000 - 0x189c46fff Security arm64  <befd826aa082355281963c056c293ad5> /System/Library/Frameworks/Security.framework/Security
0x189e0c000 - 0x189e7ffff SystemConfiguration arm64  <90fd61464db93a688f102c98383d586b> /System/Library/Frameworks/SystemConfiguration.framework/SystemConfiguration
0x189e84000 - 0x18a7f7fff UIKit arm64  <a76ac80f62d63761a00df6d7963d6116> /System/Library/Frameworks/UIKit.framework/UIKit
0x18a7f8000 - 0x18a871fff VideoToolbox arm64  <2482a5f6de143bd290a4ab73c06a43d9> /System/Library/Frameworks/VideoToolbox.framework/VideoToolbox
0x18a874000 - 0x18aad1fff WebKit arm64  <c8a57ce183f93f0ebcef00d007ad8955> /System/Library/Frameworks/WebKit.framework/WebKit
0x18aee8000 - 0x18aef5fff AOSNotification arm64  <caa8fa62f5003feab65a3a7223cb3075> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/AOSNotification.framework/AOSNotification
0x18b080000 - 0x18b0d8fff AccountsDaemon arm64  <eb703bf4a0be3563b41176632541fd57> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/AccountsDaemon.framework/AccountsDaemon
0x18b0dc000 - 0x18b102fff AccountsUI arm64  <e9d96429fdf53150a2acc067a5a697dd> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/AccountsUI.framework/AccountsUI
0x18b104000 - 0x18b109fff AggregateDictionary arm64  <dd28c9b1ca24337fab4294bf5475877d> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/AggregateDictionary.framework/AggregateDictionary
0x18b308000 - 0x18b33cfff AirPlaySupport arm64  <fbb5e1b70d7a3f4bb713d825cd350b07> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/AirPlaySupport.framework/AirPlaySupport
0x18b584000 - 0x18b5cefff AppSupport arm64  <86ab52065dea3998995772a358fb2863> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/AppSupport.framework/AppSupport
0x18b5d0000 - 0x18b623fff AppleAccount arm64  <fe5bbd847ea032288a4b696dbdfa46f9> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/AppleAccount.framework/AppleAccount
0x18b72c000 - 0x18b774fff AppleJPEG arm64  <b561b90978b23fd28662287df22f9988> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/AppleJPEG.framework/AppleJPEG
0x18b788000 - 0x18b79cfff ApplePushService arm64  <f9b2c8d646463ea8a68cc6de897a7260> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/ApplePushService.framework/ApplePushService
0x18b7a0000 - 0x18b7a9fff AppleSRP arm64  <7a5d169c15b83573a29f1c018c8ecbb8> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/AppleSRP.framework/AppleSRP
0x18b7bc000 - 0x18b7c7fff AssertionServices arm64  <181016bbc24930e88d3f764e0b160de4> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/AssertionServices.framework/AssertionServices
0x18b7c8000 - 0x18b7e3fff AssetsLibraryServices arm64  <fedd064152903bbb99207a51c41d3ba4> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/AssetsLibraryServices.framework/AssetsLibraryServices
0x18b7e4000 - 0x18b80efff AssistantServices arm64  <035de1f49fa33b3b91c4203482c763d1> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/AssistantServices.framework/AssistantServices
0x18b848000 - 0x18b84cfff BTLEAudioController arm64  <8a61f02c293931e4a014059d607e8b3c> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/BTLEAudioController.framework/BTLEAudioController
0x18b850000 - 0x18b86cfff BackBoardServices arm64  <5ec9ecf7eece37ac974e53659e7417b2> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/BackBoardServices.framework/BackBoardServices
0x18b874000 - 0x18b8b1fff BaseBoard arm64  <2881cb6cc6ad321f92e5d83198b5427d> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/BaseBoard.framework/BaseBoard
0x18b8cc000 - 0x18b8d3fff BluetoothManager arm64  <2fa00509fec23b4fa1cfba64d2b64cdb> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/BluetoothManager.framework/BluetoothManager
0x18b8d4000 - 0x18b904fff Bom arm64  <c7d34563774c3bf7bbf82e0c904401a0> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/Bom.framework/Bom
0x18b9fc000 - 0x18ba2cfff CalendarFoundation arm64  <5893bfdb52643294a1d100adc4e351c8> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/CalendarFoundation.framework/CalendarFoundation
0x18bb64000 - 0x18bb6efff CaptiveNetwork arm64  <01ff3bd724ba317dab6670af31f9ba65> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/CaptiveNetwork.framework/CaptiveNetwork
0x18bb70000 - 0x18bcbafff Celestial arm64  <f7a90143c5e7395ab00aeeee6a228df5> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/Celestial.framework/Celestial
0x18bccc000 - 0x18bce7fff CertInfo arm64  <0f2399064fcf3f5588a2633e661062da> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/CertInfo.framework/CertInfo
0x18bce8000 - 0x18bceefff CertUI arm64  <951923b64be436358d056768cbd24029> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/CertUI.framework/CertUI
0x18be38000 - 0x18be5cfff ChunkingLibrary arm64  <30aed725b5c732ac88692cd4b3d5f771> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/ChunkingLibrary.framework/ChunkingLibrary
0x18c3b4000 - 0x18c3b6fff CommonAuth arm64  <be739a349719388087584ff4b16e0a0d> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/CommonAuth.framework/CommonAuth
0x18c3b8000 - 0x18c3cafff CommonUtilities arm64  <5be3c0850f4a319b82f8c1dcd4d973b4> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/CommonUtilities.framework/CommonUtilities
0x18c3cc000 - 0x18c3d0fff CommunicationsFilter arm64  <4f1199a6854739f7bb1957e507d0ec38> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/CommunicationsFilter.framework/CommunicationsFilter
0x18c458000 - 0x18c45dfff ConstantClasses arm64  <9493983ef0293b17a6f636fca00ac8f8> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/ConstantClasses.framework/ConstantClasses
0x18c460000 - 0x18c49efff ContentIndex arm64  <9da2129df0a43aa28b43f3d0346bbe8c> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/ContentIndex.framework/ContentIndex
0x18c4a0000 - 0x18c4a4fff CoreAUC arm64  <d442ac9b2406333ca4ee8442d5773473> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/CoreAUC.framework/CoreAUC
0x18c4d8000 - 0x18c538fff CoreDAV arm64  <7a5044a015d13f2e95415ff4ec2aa07a> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/CoreDAV.framework/CoreDAV
0x18c53c000 - 0x18c55afff CoreDuet arm64  <ddd8a946458a34c9a32c881c2a1febdd> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/CoreDuet.framework/CoreDuet
0x18c560000 - 0x18c572fff CoreDuetDaemonProtocol arm64  <1276496c0dbd35c8a1e4ec7a4203f9cb> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/CoreDuetDaemonProtocol.framework/CoreDuetDaemonProtocol
0x18c57c000 - 0x18c57efff CoreDuetDebugLogging arm64  <72ad30b62ded3c8b8bfa5f5fa41099ec> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/CoreDuetDebugLogging.framework/CoreDuetDebugLogging
0x18c83c000 - 0x18c8ecfff CorePDF arm64  <adf469f9c026312683165e9c4af258c4> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/CorePDF.framework/CorePDF
0x18c960000 - 0x18c96bfff CoreRecents arm64  <8be1636faf27390bbf3a4a6517df51f9> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/CoreRecents.framework/CoreRecents
0x18c9f8000 - 0x18ca1cfff CoreServicesInternal arm64  <88aea9acfb373a28b285a7d252825b85> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/CoreServicesInternal.framework/CoreServicesInternal
0x18cc80000 - 0x18cd12fff CoreUI arm64  <8e33909dd1f43590bae63cf4d4991e34> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/CoreUI.framework/CoreUI
0x18cd14000 - 0x18cd8ffff CoreUtils arm64  <52b4bea57e9538a4ac29870663099d58> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/CoreUtils.framework/CoreUtils
0x18cd90000 - 0x18cd96fff CrashReporterSupport arm64  <a7fda94a40ea34149b6bce8d445dc863> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/CrashReporterSupport.framework/CrashReporterSupport
0x18cd98000 - 0x18cd9ffff DAAPKit arm64  <ed341cafa6743a6f9305f98a5b8f5781> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/DAAPKit.framework/DAAPKit
0x18cdac000 - 0x18cdfbfff DataAccess arm64  <1105560511863eb4b050878bd140bbb6> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/DataAccess.framework/DataAccess
0x18d058000 - 0x18d07efff DataAccessExpress arm64  <505a289392f53ec8876896504d322c81> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/DataAccessExpress.framework/DataAccessExpress
0x18d08c000 - 0x18d0a8fff DataDetectorsCore arm64  <822b0eee14c834dca63c74d02b02b593> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/DataDetectorsCore.framework/DataDetectorsCore
0x18d0b0000 - 0x18d0ccfff DataDetectorsUI arm64  <0e08e67cdd8736379009e917e7b4cd36> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/DataDetectorsUI.framework/DataDetectorsUI
0x18d0d0000 - 0x18d0d7fff DataMigration arm64  <08afb9df68c13565bff259d40bcebda4> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/DataMigration.framework/DataMigration
0x18d0e0000 - 0x18d0e1fff DiagnosticLogCollection arm64  <7e3171d82a413732a9bc272d1557bdc1> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/DiagnosticLogCollection.framework/DiagnosticLogCollection
0x18d0e4000 - 0x18d104fff DictionaryServices arm64  <4f4e43c76ec834af8829e0bc89dbe53b> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/DictionaryServices.framework/DictionaryServices
0x18d12c000 - 0x18d152fff EAP8021X arm64  <7d312758fb02305dacd9c276be5f4ad4> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/EAP8021X.framework/EAP8021X
0x18d27c000 - 0x18d27efff FTClientServices arm64  <03fab36097ee38f68a0db50087706497> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/FTClientServices.framework/FTClientServices
0x18d280000 - 0x18d2b2fff FTServices arm64  <7d5f2d1254143799abf5ccc3409addee> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/FTServices.framework/FTServices
```

Comment: You have to desymbolicate the crash log before you can read it

Comment: Have you run it on a device? Does it work for you?

Comment: @jrturton Yes , i have tested iphone 5S , it is working fine ...

Comment: you need to symbolicate this crash log file for that you need to have. .dysm file for the same build that you submited or you found crash on application than follow this step given in link. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1460892/symbolicating-iphone-app-crash-reports this symbolicate your crash so you get proper method name or reason why you application got carsh on launching.if you not able to trace symbolicate crash reason upload syblicate crash report here. hope this will help you

Comment: You should use something like crashlytics to make symbolicating crashes easy. https://www.crashlytics.com